# Microsoft Azure Subscription

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have an **Azure account** and in this account I have multiple directory I want to access one of them on server explorer on visual studio but it is showing this subscription is not supported by server explorer. 
[image]

In this image before the checkbox a yellow warning box is showing **"This Subscription is not supported by server explorer"**. Please suggest if any one have any idea.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you still have this problem? What kind of access do you have in those subscriptions? Co-admin, subscription owner or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question is asked long back and got *many upvotes*. I wish to answer it which might useful for someone in the future.

As mentioned in the above comment by ***juunas***. This is due to the permission Scope of the user.

You need at least **[Co-Admin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-add-change-azure-subscription-administrator)** access for managing Azure services in VS.

Also, you can confirm with the reference [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/183249/azure-subscription-not-supported-by-server-explore.html)